# How to serve static content based on locale in springboot

Tags: spring-boot

is it possible to use someone's locale to serve different static content with springboot?

this is what my code currently does

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/en-ca/**")
          .addResourceLocations("/angular-output/en-CA");   
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/fr-ca/**")
          .addResourceLocations("/angular-output/fr-CA");
    }
}
```

but this method only allows me to setup mappings from a url-path to a file-path with no intermediate step to consider someone's locale to pick the file-path I want to use.

I wish I could do something like

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MyConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
          .addResourceHandler("/**").addResourceLocationSelector(
              new ResourceLocationSelector() {
                  @Override
                  public string select() {
                      if (LocaleContextHolder.getLocale() == Locale.English) {
                          return "/angular-output/en-CA";
                      } else { 
                          return "/angular-output/fr-CA";
                      }
                  }
              }
          )
    }
}
```

I've had little luck trying to do such a seemingly basic thing with Spring Boot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to customize static endpoints at request time by using the [ResourceResolver API](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/servlet/resource/ResourceResolver.html).

How it works:

1. On the ResourceHandlerRegistry, add a resource handler, and optionally abase resource location.
2. Use `resourceChain` function to specify that from this point, you want to add intermediate path resolvers, that will customize static content location depending on user query.

Here is a little example that will serve content from `static` directory from the classpath, but that use a resource resolver to append a lang directory ([complete working example here](https://github.com/alexismanin/demo-locale-hello-spring))

```java
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class StaticContentConfiguration implements WebMvcConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry
                .addResourceHandler("/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/static/")
                // Maybe you will want to set it to true to activate cache
                .resourceChain(false) 
                // This will add a suffix to the above resource location by analyzin
                .addResolver(new LocaleResolver());
    }

    /**
     * Modify static content path initially resolved by spring to include a locale dependent piece.
     */
    private class LocaleResolver implements ResourceResolver {

        @Override
        public Resource resolveResource(HttpServletRequest request, String requestPath, List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
            final var lang = solveLang(request, "en").toLowerCase(Locale.ROOT);
            for (Resource loc: locations) {
                try {
                    // IMPORTANT: it looks like the createRelative method needs that appended directories end with a slash 
                    final Resource langSpecializedResource = loc.createRelative(lang+"/");
                    if (langSpecializedResource.exists()) {
                        // Let spring build final path from modified prefix.
                        return chain.resolveResource(request, requestPath, List.of(langSpecializedResource));
                    }
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    throw new UncheckedIOException("Failure while resolving paths", e);
                }
            }

            // TODO: that does NOT propagate properly
            throw new HttpClientErrorException(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST, "Language not supported");
        }

        @Override
        public String resolveUrlPath(String resourcePath, List<? extends Resource> locations, ResourceResolverChain chain) {
            throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet");
        }
    }

    /**
     * Try to extract user language from request. Search in order:
     * <ol>
     *     <li>for a <pre>lang</pre> query parameter</li>
     *     <li>for a valid <pre>Accept-Language</pre> header</li>
     * </ol>
     *
     * @param request User request to analyze.
     * @param fallback The default language value to use.
     * @return found language, or given fallback if none can be extracted from input request.
     */
    private String solveLang(final HttpServletRequest request, final String fallback) {
        if (request == null) return fallback;

        final var langs = request.getParameterValues("lang");
        if (langs != null && langs.length > 0) return langs[0];

        final var header = request.getHeader(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT_LANGUAGE);
        if (header != null) {
            return Locale.forLanguageTag(header).getLanguage();
        }

        return fallback;
    }
}
```